# Jquery not running on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have some jquery which is used after a postback to the page on which i take a value that was set in a hidden field and find the div corresponding to that value. I then do some css class changes on the div and its contents. I have similar code for the click event of this but need this to work on page startup.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amwz/vks4n5bo/

and the jquery I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var currPackage = $("#HF_Package").val();

$("#" + currPackage).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
$("#" + currPackage).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-footer').removeClass('highlight');
$("#" + currPackage).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
$("#" + currPackage).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
$("#" + currPackage).find('.package-footer').addClass('highlight');
});
```

EDIT___

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #E/CS/PSTN_P1

The console in the fiddle gives me this error, although my jquery is valid no?

Comment: did you look at the console in fiddle?

Comment: @Mritunjay I've checked the console and got a `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #E/CS/PSTN_P1` error, although my jquery looks valid

Comment: That isn't a valid element id.

Comment: you are trying to access element by `#E/CS/PSTN_P1` which is invalid id.

Comment: @MohitArora but that is the id of the div?

Comment: Look at this how to write valid HTML ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
 var currPackage = $("#HF_Package").val().replace(new RegExp("/",'g'),"\\/");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/vks4n5bo/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your HTML element ids, they contain invalid characters.

To have a look which characters are allowed follow [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)